# how to return an array with vlookup as the criteria in excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to return an array with only those entries which satisfy a specific vlookup criteria.
I have 2 tables for example:

**table 1**

| item | value |
| --- | --- |
| red | 1 |
| blue | 2 |
| green | 3 |
| joker | 4 |
| lion | 5 |
| just | 6 |
| romeo | 7 |
| red | 8 |

**table 2**

| Item | desc |
| --- | --- |
| red | Colors |
| blue | Colors |
| green | Colors |
| joker | else |
| lion | else |
| just | not |
| romeo | name |

I want to average the column 2 of table 1 but only those rows which corresponds to colors in table 2
i.e. i want to average numbers in table 1 with red, blue green values in col 1
I dont want to add a extra col in table 1 with vlookup values.
additionally It would be nice if I could return an array with the above conditions from table 1

Comment: What do you mean by return array? What result do you expected from you given data?

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVERAGEIFS()` function.

```
=IF(E3="Colors",AVERAGEIFS($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9,D3),"")
```

[image]